# How to send html/plain-text mails based on user settings?

Tags: 8, emails

Using mail function i am send mails to multiple users with comma separated values in Drupal 8. But in that mail id users, some users selected mail preference as html and some users selected plain-text settings. So how can i send the html/plain-text mails programatically based on users settings?

Comment: You'll have to send the emails in a loop instead

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about hardcoding (not interface), you have to loop through the
addressee list, load that user, and based on his preferences send html, or plain text.